# Stoke's formula for a sphere

Tags: calculus

I have a question, raised form kinetic theory (pure mathematical). 
Imagine, that $\Psi (\overrightarrow{r},\overrightarrow{p},t)$ - sufficiently smooth function, where $\overrightarrow{r}$ - radius vector, $\overrightarrow{p}$ - unit vector of orientation, $t$ - time.

Can someone explain me, how to proove this identities (I think, Stoke's theorem must be used here):

$$
\int_{S} \overrightarrow{p} \left(\nabla_p \cdot \left( \frac {d\overrightarrow{p}} {dt} \Psi\right) \right)d\overrightarrow{p}=-\int_{S} \frac {d\overrightarrow{p}} {dt} \Psi d\overrightarrow{p} 
$$

$$
\int_{S}  \nabla_p \cdot  \left( \frac {d\overrightarrow{p}} {dt} \Psi\right)  d\overrightarrow{p}=0
$$

Here $S$ is the surface of the unit sphere, so we integrate over a unit sphere.

This formula are used in physical article. I am sure, that you don't need more information for this identities.

Edit: If this is simple Integration by parts, I am interested, what boundary term is, and why it is zero

Comment: hint: integration by parts

Comment: Thanks, I figured that. Can you explain me, why boundary term disappears? I don't know, what boundary is here

Comment: I have an explanation that avoids differential geometry in the appendix of this article: http://faculty.missouri.edu/~stephen/preprints/pde-sphere.html

Comment: But if you want to use Stoke's Theorem, the clever thing is that on the surface of the sphere, the boundary is the empty set.

Comment: You said that $\vec p$ is a unit vector.  Is that correct?  And, what is the relevance or $\vec r$ then?

Comment: For this problem, vector $r$ is irrelevant

Comment: Stephen, thanks for the usefull link. So, can I use Stoke's theorem here?

Comment: You can use Stokes' Theorem.  But you have to understand what it means on manifolds.  By the way, on my link I write $\bf x$ for your $\vec r$ and I write $\bf r$ for your $\vec p$.